# Sorting Numericly and by Month name

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, built-in

I have a single function that takes 3 diffrent inputs:

A dict of Days in the following formart:

```
"Day 2":Something,
"Day 1":Something,
"Day 3":Something,
"Day 5":Something,
"Day 4":Something
```

A dict of weeks:

```
"Week 2":Something,
"Week 1":Something,
"Week 4":Something,   
"Week 3":Something,
"Week 5":Something
```

A dict of months:

```
"April":Something,
"February":Something,
"March":Something,
"January":Something
```

Since they are dicts, they come in unordered. I'm manipulating them to present to the user in ordered fashion.

I'm looking for a way to split the sorted() built-in to deal with the three types.

The output should be the keys sorted numercly(days/week) and by month:

```
"Day 1"
"Day 2"
"Day 3"
"Day 4"
"Day 5"
###
"Week 1"
"Week 2"
"Week 3"
"Week 4"
"Week 5"
###
"January"
"February"
"March"
"April"
```

I know I can use Ternary Operation:

```
sorted(input_dict, key=lambda x: int(x.strip("Day ")) if "Day 1" in input_dict else sorted(input_dict, key=lambda x: int(x.strip("Week ")) if "Week 1" in input_dict else sorted...
```

But it gets quite messy.

I'm looking for how to implement the key function with a already defined function.

Something like:

```
def my_sort_function():
    # magic goes here

for n in sorted(input_dict, key=my_function):
    pass
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused here...  Can you show us some actual input (the 3 dicts) and the output you are looking for?

Comment: A list of strings is not a dict.  Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so ... Sorting your lists of days/weeks is pretty easy:

```
def sort_day_week_key(day_week_str):
    return int(day_week_str.split()[-1])
```

But you want to handle months as well.  The obvious solution is a mapping of month names to numbers:

```
import calendar
_MONTH_MAP = {m.lower(): i for i, m in enumerate(calendar.month_name[1:])}
def sort_month_names_key(m_name):
    return _MONTH_MAP[m_name.lower()]
```

Now you just want to combine those two functions.  This is pretty easy:  `try` one, if it doesn't work use the other:

```
def sort_the_stuff_key(item):
    try:
        return sort_month_names_key(item)
    except KeyError:
        return sort_day_week_key

def sort_the_stuff(some_iterable):
    return sorted(some_iterable, key=sort_the_stuff_key)
```

Of course, this sort function will give strange results if your iterable has items from more than one class of string (e.g. days and month names) but it sounds like that won't happen...

Comment: It's raising `ValueError: too many values to unpack` on `_MONTH_MAP = {m.name.lower(): i for i, m in calendar.month_name[1:]}`

Comment: @f.rodrigues -- Of course it is.  I forgot my `enumerate` :-)

Comment: Great, never thought it was that easy to sort via function. Python amazes me every day.